# Joomla Proper CMS for complex design

Tags: templates, joomla, content-management-system

i am very confused right now. I came from Wordpress,and laravel frameworks, and now i am assigned to develop Joomla! project.I thought i can easily manage to create custom template in joomla. I have been reading a lot of articles and documentation. I've manage to create a template and display modules.
But now, i need to start digging the right way to display the content and manage it in Joomla! back-end.

Here's my problem. I have home page (Long page) and inner pages (Short page). Here's the structure of my homepage

```
<html>
    ... header links and other necessary tags
<body>
    <section class="homepageonlysection1">
        <div>
            image and text here! (i made this as 1 modules in Custom HTML)
        </div>
        <div>
            video here (i made this as 1 modules in Custom HTML)
        </div>
    </section >
    <section class="homepageonlysection2">
        <div>
            form here (i made this as 1 modules in Custom HTML)
        </div>
        <div>
            image and text here! (i made this as 1 modules in Custom HTML)
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="homepageonlysection3">
        <div>
            image and text here! (i made this as 1 modules in Custom HTML)
        </div>
        <div>
        video here (i made this as 1 modules in Custom HTML)
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my inner pages

```
<html>
 ... header links and other necessary tags
<body>
    <section class="innerpagessectiononly1">
        <div>
            Article Content (i will do as jdoc:inlucde type="component")
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="innerpagessectiononly2">
        <div>
            sidebar Content (i will do this as 1 modules in Custom HTML)
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Those template are really different.

Problem 1 : How can i make my inner pages if my homepage structure is very different? Or

Problem 2 :How can i make display my section (homepageonlysection) in home page only and display (innerpagessectiononly) in inner pages only?

Problem 3 : Is there a Advance Custom Field (ACF for wordpress) as joomla extension ?

Please advice. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I recommend is really digging into the core templates (both front and backend) to understand how things work. In particular Isis the backend template illustrates a number of complex options.

Now, overall I think you probably do not want to do the homepage the way you are doing it, since it will be very inflexible and hard to change. On the other hand it's possible that you want it inflexible and hard to change. In reality you may not need to have separate layouts at all or the differences may be minimal and may not require any special code at all.

So, **first**, [this document](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page) explains how to determine if you are on the home page. So you can clearly pretty easily test for that and then enclose your two separate designs in the true and false conditions. This is basically what you see in Isis. In your case you can place one or more module position inside the condition. In fact you could make it so this layout does not even load a component. Then you can just make an empty article and make the home page a single article link to that empty article. (I would put that article into a separate landing page category)

A **second** option if you really want to have a totally different design on the home page is to make a totally separate template for the home page.  If say you called this "my home template" and your other template "my everywhere else template" what you could do is make "my everywhere else template" the default and then on the default (homepage) menu item assign the "my home template" template. In this special template you can even use the module  jdoc:include (instead of modules) to call specific modules in highly customized ways. I would suggest you go read the docs on that. You can even set the options and the chrome right in the template.

However, I think you are missing a key feature of Joomla. In your question you have not said what kind of  menu link you are planning to use for your home page. The **third** option is that for the homepage you use the same template but a specific alternate layout that you use for this page. For your case what you would most likely want to do, assuming that you are not using the featured articles layout type anywhere else (i.e. that no articles are marked featured), is to make your homepage using an articles > featured menu link.  Then you can assign all the modules you made to the home page via the menu modules tab.  Depending on how your module positions are in the template it could just be that they will float up.

Your design is not a particularly unusual or complex however. Many Joomla homepages consist of multiple structured sections of text and media. These are made with menu types such as "featured" and "category blog." The advantage of using these menu types is that then you are storing your content in articles and these are much easier to manage. ALso you don't have to give someone access to the module manager in order to allow them to edit these snippets of content. So the **fourth** and possibly best approach is to use one of these standard content layouts. For example if you were to make a category called "home page content" and then put the content for each of the modules in a separate article and (assuming you want a consistent structure) put the image for each of them into the structured intro text image field, you can then make a "category blog" menu link to the "home page content" category as you default (home page) menu link.  Then what you can do is make one or more layout override for those individual items that gives the exact layout you want.  Assuming that they are all the same, you can select that as a alternate layout in your menu link. Actually even if they are not all the same you can just do a more complex layout instead of looping through the list and doing the same thing for each article, do each one separately.

A **fifth** approach is to use an alternative layout instead of an alternate layout. The difference there is that you would give the layout a new name (in either the category or featured  view) and then you will have the additional flexibility of being able to create options in the menu link that are different than those for the normal category/featured views.  It's up to you to decide what you might want to add there.

There are other options as well, because Joomla has a very strong template community and they like to have a lot of flexibility.  But that will get you started.